# Why setting resizeMode to center/repeat making my image small in react native?

Tags: css, reactjs, react-native

When I set the `resizeMode` to the centre or repeat in Image, then it makes the image small than the original size maintaining the aspect ratio.
In the below code it can maintain its aspect ratio and put it inside the image container without changing the size, but I don't understand why it is changing the size of image

I am using static image import
The code for normal image is

```
<Image source={require('../res/images/elon.jpeg')} />
```

and the code for centered Image is

```
<Image
        source={require('../res/images/elon.jpeg')}
        style={{
          height: 300,
          width: 300,
          resizeMode: 'center',
          backgroundColor: 'grey',
        }}
      />
```

Note: the given size (300 x 300) is bigger than the original image's size which is 258 x 195.

Please explain why the image shrink in the second case when I am using the center as resizeMode

[image: screenshot from ios simulator]

Answer (score 0):

Does the parent has some padding? That could be the issue.

Another idea could be to set resizeMode to “cover”

Comment: No padding. I am not creating anything, I am trying out different resize mode and this center and repeat mode caught my attention